# How to find an exact match of a string in array of strings using underscore

Tags: node.js, arrays, underscore.js

I have the following string

```
const item = "CACHED ITEM 2"
```

and I have the following array

```
const names = ["CACHED ITEM 1"];
```

now I am using underscore to check if item in the array of name using the following code

```
if (_.contains(names),item){ 
    console.log(true)
}else{
    console.log(false)
}
```

If I run the above code the result is true event though item variable does not have an exact match in names array. How can I enforce exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the 2nd parameter (item) inside contains's bracket.

See the below code.

```
if (_.contains(names, item)){ 
    console.log(true)
} else {
    console.log(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
// item is passed as parameter to if , which ll be treated as OR     
if (_.contains(names),item)
```

[_.contains](https://underscorejs.org/#contains)

```
const item = "CACHED ITEM 2"
const names = ["CACHED ITEM 1"];
if (_.contains(names,item))
    console.log(true)
else
    console.log(false)
```